# What happens to mod_jk sticky sessions on apache httpd reload|graceful

Tags: apache, session, mod-jk

As said in the title, i'd like to know if active mod_jk sticky sessions will get preserved if i restart apache webserver with reload or graceful (running on linux (centos5)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will.

The stickiness works by looking at the node identifier in the session cookie - mod_jk looks at the node name in the cookie, and sends it to the worker that matches that name.  It doesn't actually maintain an internal table of sessions, that doesn't scale well. It's effectivelt stateless from that perspective, so a restart will not affect stickiness.